# squid with SSH dynamic redirect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, ssh, squid

I have a working SOCKS proxy, which I set up with the command `ssh -D 9999 user@host`. As mentioned, this works great, and when I browse the public IP is that of the server that I connected to via SSH.

My network overview is:

local pc --> server (local network, running `ssh -D` command) --> remote server (proxy)

I have run into an issue with a device that can only use a HTTP proxy, so I have set up squid on the local network server. I can access the proxy without any issues, but the IP address displayed is that of my local network, not the proxy.

How can I configure squid to use the socks proxy that I have set up via SSH?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not programming-related and thus is offtopic here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Squid, consider using [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html) or [Polipo](https://www.irif.fr/%7Ejch/software/polipo/manual/SOCKS-parent-proxies.html), which allows you to forward connections to a upstream SOCKS proxy.

```
[device]---8118---[privoxy/polipo]---1080---[socks proxy]---80---[http server]
```

That said, you may still need to

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to remove the X-Forwarded-For headers from your requests to the remote proxy.

On the local squid server's config file, try adding

```
forwarded_for off
```